# Add values to in-cell dropdown list

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to add some values to `in-cell dropdown list` from Spreadsheet using Google Script but I can't get it working...

This is my code:

```
  var justRS = rs.report_suites;
  var rsID = [];
  for(var prop in justRS) {
    rsID.push(justRS[prop].rsid);
  }

  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getSheets()[4].getRange("A1");
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule).setValue(rsID);
```

The cell "A1" should contain an `in-cell dropdown list` with values from `rsID` array...

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, this is the solution:

```
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[4].getRange("A1");
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(rsID, true).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```